# Compiling With LDC2 and GDC

Tags: d, gdc

I had ldc2 and gdc compiled from source and working up until a month ago.  Nothing has changed, except I can't remember the variable(s) I would set in the terminal to get ldc2 and gdc to work.

I get the following errors when trying to compile D source code;

gdc:

> $
>   /home/Code/D/gdc/Bin/usr/local/bin/gdc
>   -o t4 t4.d                   /home/Code/D/gdc/Bin/usr/local/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.4.5/cc1d:
>   error while loading shared libraries:
>   libmpfr.so.1: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory

ldc2:

> $ /home/Code/D/ldc2/bin/ldc2 -o t4
>   t4.d /home/Code/D/ldc2/bin/ldc2: error
>   while loading shared libraries:
>   libconfig++.so.8: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory

I can't remember if it was just an addition to PATH or something to DFLAGS.  Any ideas?

---

EDIT:
Recompiling both LDC2 and GDC solved the problem, but I still don't know why I was getting the errors.

Answer (score 1):

The error with LDC means that you (re)moved libconfig++ after you compiled it. `PATH` and `DFLAGS` are unrelated, but as Dan noted in his answer, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` can be used to add extra locations to the search path.

If you want to have a self-contained installation for whatever reason, you can set the RPATH to the `bin` directory and copy libconfig++ there, as it is done when building the binary packages: https://github.com/ldc-developers/ldc-scripts/blob/master/ldc2-packaging/2-build-ldc.sh#L18.

Same story for the GDC error – it depends on the GNU MPFR library, which was either removed, or replaced with an incompatible version during an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur if the `.so` files are not in your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, I think.